# returning values from decorated functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I have the following decorated function:

```
import time
def logging_time(func):
    """Decorator that logs time"""
    def logger():
        """Function that logs time"""
        start = time.time()
        func()
        print(f"Calling {func.__name__}: {time.time() - start:.5f}")

    return logger
     
@logging_time
def calculate_sum():
     return sum(range(10000))
```

When I run `calculate_sum()` I get `Calling calculate_sum: 0.00043` which is the output of the `@logging_time`.

How can I also retrieve the `return` value of the `calculate_sum` function as well ? Why isnt the `sum(range(10000))` returned as well ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply save result where you call the function and return it

```
import time
def logging_time(func):
    """Decorator that logs time"""
    def logger():
        """Function that logs time"""
        start = time.time()
        result = func()  # save result here
        print(f"Calling {func.__name__}: {time.time() - start:.5f}")
        return result  # return it here

    return logger
     
@logging_time
def calculate_sum():
     return sum(range(10000))
```

Answer (score 1):

just store the return value and return it

```
import time
def logging_time(func):
    """Decorator that logs time"""
    def logger():
        """Function that logs time"""
        start = time.time()
        result = func()
        print(f"Calling {func.__name__}: {time.time() - start:.5f}")
        return result
    return logger
     
@logging_time
def calculate_sum():
     return sum(range(10000))

print(calculate_sum())
```

Result:

```
Calling calculate_sum: 0.00012
49995000
```